# Google Cloud: Timed out waiting for an update from the worker

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I use the Apache Beam Python SDK together with google cloud, here a wrote a class that I use to process some business ruling. I ran a pipeline with 9 different business rules which all use the same class in a slightly different way but the broad idea is always the same.

Now I added a 10th rule in the pipe and all of the sudden Google cloud is giving me the following error:

```
Root cause: Timed out waiting for an update from the worker. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#worker-lost-contact.
      Worker ID: xxxxxxxxx-01180119-o444-harness-gqz6
```

The problem does not come from the new rule but from the number of rules, i tested this by removing an older rule while still runing the new one (in total 9 rules) and everything works.

I tried ingesting only half of the input data with 10 business rules and still the same error.

I upped the max number of workers to 40 workers and still the same error (while with 9 rules, 20 workers suffice).

I tried to use more diskspace for the workers (`disk_size_gb=1,000`) or tried using more powerfull workers (`n1-highcpu-4` or `n1-highmem-4`) but the same error keeps occuring once I add the 10th business rule ..

Could anybody have any idea what I could try? Google cloud is giving almost no info in the logging ..

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail on how this business logic class looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Actual the above error will show based on the different type of cause but you can troubleshooting to following steps below:
Gather Information:
Analyze worker logs for errors and resource patterns.
Verify worker configuration (machine type, disk size, etc.).
Check network connectivity using tools like ping or traceroute.

Address Potential Causes:
Worker Crash: Redeploy pipeline, increase resources, review code.
Network Issues: Resolve bottlenecks, consider different network options.
Resource Exhaustion: Increase resources, optimize code, use Dataflow Shuffle.
Code Errors: Debug code, review pipeline logic.
Dataflow Service Issues: Check service status, contact support.

Monitor and Adjust:

Re-run pipeline after changes.
Monitor worker performance through logs and metrics.
Adjust resources or optimizations as needed.
Consider Dataflow Shuffle for disk usage reduction.
Experiment with different machine types for optimal configuration.
Utilize Dataflow's logging and monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

This error is covered on the  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#worker-lost-contact page.